# boot-repair appears to work, GRUB does not appear

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, grubrescue, boot-repair

So I am a completely new to linux, bear with me here.

I made a partition and installed ubuntu 14.04. I did not disable secure boot when I had installed ubuntu, though I have disabled it now.

At first GRUB would appear upon startup so I could select the OS. Once I went into windows again GRUB has disappeared. If I get into the boot devices options before startup, I see OS Boot Manager and "Ubuntu". If I select ubuntu it boots windows instead. The only way I can get into Ubuntu is by booting from the USB I installed with and running the live session.

To remedy this problem I downloaded and ran boot-repair. It appeared to work. There were no errors and the task ran to completion, provided me with some terminal lines to execute, which I did and they completed without error.

I shut down and start up, windows boots automatically and GRUB never appears. What can I do about this?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the link below:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Refer to the 'Advanced Options' section.

Please refer to the first screen shot, where under the  Advanced Options> Main Options,there is a check list named 'Unhide boot menu'. Make sure it is ticked and set time (in seconds) for how long you with for the GRUB to appear. Click 'Apply' and restart it. Check if that helps. Offcourse, the boot-repair needs to run in Live Mode.

Regards.